# I am not able to console log the data taken from text field passed by POST method on the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lodash, ejs

I am not able to console log the data taken from text field passed by POST method on the terminal.It is first logging blank and then it is logging the data.
I have already declared the variable "stateName" global in my app.js file.

If i am trying to log "stateName" from res.on("end", function(res) then it is working fine but outside it , its working as mentioned above.Please help me i am a beginner.

```
var stateName=" ";
    app.post("/",function(req, res)
    {
        
        const userInput=req.body.input;
        const inputTitleCase=_.startCase(_.toLower(userInput));//conversion to tile case.
         
    /*********  API CALL *************************************************************************** 
    <API credentials hidden>  
    Data given by API call stored in **options variable**
    */
       
       const request=http.request(options, function (res) {
        const chunks = [];
        
    
        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        
        res.on("end", function(res) {
            
             body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
             parsedDetails=JSON.parse(body);
             objectArray = Object.entries(parsedDetails);//converts ab object into array of key value pairs
        
          
             for(var i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++)
            {
                if(objectArray[i][0]==inputTitleCase)
                {
                     index=i;
                    break;
                }
            }  
                   stateName=objectArray[index][1].state;data.push(stateName);
                    curedCases=objectArray[index][1].cured; data.push(curedCases);                       
        });
        console.log(stateName);
    });
    request.end(); 
    });
```

Comment: maybe it helps to set the encoding to `utf-8` or to do `chuncks.push(chunck.toString())`

Comment: they show working example here opting for toString https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect

Comment: here is example with utf-8 encoding https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers

Comment: You can also check out the pipeline function https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback

Comment: stateName is assigned a value inside `res.on("end"` callback ... so, where you console.log it, it hasn't been assigned a value yet - that's how asynchrony works

Comment: @JaromandaX could you please tell me how can i access that value outside its scope

Comment: @Neha - by definition, you can not access a value outside its scope